# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre lapply, do.call y Map?

Tags: r, rstudio

En el uso cotidiano de R, he visto que se usa en muchas ocasiones un conjunto de funciones como son: `lapply`, `do.call` y `Map`, quisiera saber cuales son sus diferencias, y si es posible un ejemplo para ver en que ocasiones usarlas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las funciones `lapply`, `do.call` y `Map` tienen una funcionalidad que puede resultar bastante parecida en ciertos contextos. Veamos:

- [**`lapply`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html): Esta función retorna una lista de la misma longitud que la lista de entrada `X`, y dónde cada elemento será el resultado de aplicar una función `FUN` a los correspondientes elementos de la lista de entrada.
- [**`Map`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html): Aplica una función a los elementos correspondientes a un  o o más vectores dados.
- [**`do.call`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html): Construye y ejecuta una llamada de función desde un nombre o una función y una lista de argumentos indicados.

Más allá que son funciones distintas, con parámetros y particularidades se puede decir que `lapply` y `Map` funcionan de forma muy parecida, hacen las veces de ciclos implícitos, tal como dice la documentación, aplican una función a cada elemento de una lista. `do.call` por el contrario, es una función que nada tiene que ver con las anteriores, aunque claro, en el contexto de aplicar una función de cierto tipo a una lista, podría parecernos que se asemeja a las otras. Veamos un sencillo ejemplo, la aplicación de `sum` sobre una lista:

```
l = list(1:3, 4:6)
lapply(l, sum) 
Map(sum, l)
```

En ambos casos el retorno es el mismo, una lista con la misma cantidad de elementos de la lista de entrada, es decir 2, pero cada elemento será la aplicación de `sum` sobre, en este caso, los elementos de cada vector `c(1,2,3)` y `c(4,5,6)`, es decir:

```
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 15
```

Conceptualmente es como si estaríamos haciendo `list(sum(l[[1]]), sum(l[[2]]))`. Por el contrario:

```
do.call(sum, l)
[1] 21
```

Aplica el `sum` sobre el conjunto total de los elementos de la lista, estamos haciendo en realidad: `sum( l[[1]], l[[2]])`.

`do.call` es algo totalmente distinto en su concepción a las otras, es básicamente una función, para construir y llamar a otra de forma dinámica. En el anterior ejemplo, pareciera que todas hacen algo mas o menos algo parecido, pero esto es debido a que `sum` en particular, puede recibir múltiples parámetros que serán tratados todos como entrada para sumar, por lo que resulta, de alguna forma, "compatible" con el `do.call` tal como lo estamos usando. Para ver más claro como funciona `do.call`, supongamos este ejemplo:

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd=1)

 [1]  9.373546 10.183643  9.164371 11.595281 10.329508
```

Nada raro, un `rnorm` invocado con tres parámetros. Ahora imaginemos que esos tres parámetros, los tenemos en una lista, podremos entonces hacer entonces:

```
set.seed(1)
do.call(rnorm, list(5,10,1)) # equivalente a rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd=1)

[1]  9.373546 10.183643  9.164371 11.595281 10.329508
```

Podemos verificar que `do.call` "mapea" la lista `list(5,10,1)` a cada uno de los parámetros de la función que queremos invocar, en este caso `rnorm`, en el orden definido por la propia función, y luego, efectivamente la ejecuta.

#### Resumiendo

- `lapply` y `Map` son útiles en el contexto de aplicar una función a cada ítem de un objeto, vector, lista, etc. Siempre recibiremos una lista de la misma longitud de la lista de entrada y cuyo resultado es la aplicación de una función a cada elemento
- `do.call` sirve para generar de manera dinámica una llamada única a una función, el retorno dependerá de cada función, y la lista que le pasemos debe coincidir con la cantidad y la clase de cada uno de los parámetros de la función.