# ¿Cómo generalizar el proceso de estandarización en el caso de tener una base de datos con más de una serie temporal?

Tags: r, predicción

**Contexto teórico**

Cuando queremos hacer la **predicción de una serie temporal** suele ser conveniente estandarizar las series temporales en varianza  y en media.

En cuanto a la **varianza** sé que hay que utilizar la transformada Box-Cox. En RStudio está el comando `BoxCox.lambda()` para elegir el valor del parámetro de lambda y luego el comando `BoxCox()` para estandarizar nuestra serie temporal en varianza.

Por otro lado, para la **media** son útiles los gráficos `Acf()` (FAS) donde se ve si hay raíces unitarias. También podemos saber si la serie es estacionaria con el test de Dickey-Fuller `adf.test()`, el test KPSS `kpss.test()` Phillips-Perron `pp.test()`. Si con estos test saliese que la serie temporal es estacionaria, la diferenciariamos con el comando `diff()`.

**Pregunta práctica**

Mi problema es que estos comandos sirven para una serie temporal.
En mi caso, estoy trabajando con 119 series temporales.

Mi base de datos inicial es la siguiente:

[image: Mi base de datos]

Pero para trabajar con series temporales he creado un pivot table `df_pivot <- xtabs(datos$Indice~datos$Fecha+datos$Codigo)`. Por tanto, esta es la tabla con la que trabajo en RStudio:

[image: Pivot table de la base de datos]

Es decir, que la primera columna sería la fecha y el resto de columnas son cada serie temporal, teniendo así un dataframe de 120 columnas y 206 filas.

¿ Me podríais ayudar en automatizar o generalizar el proceso de estandarización para no tener que ir uno por uno ?

Se me ha ocurrido que tal vez, en el caso de la media, podría ver si la mayoría de las series necesitan diferencias y en ese caso aplicarles a todas.

Gracias !!

Comment: Bienvenido... Para saber como funciona el sitio te recomiendo hagas un [tour]... Y para evitar que tu publicación tenga puntuaciones negativas o reportes te recomiendo que vayas a [ask] y luego edites la pregunta según corresponda... Que llevas hecho hasta ahora??

Comment: Maider, para el problema que planteas sería importante saber con qué estructura de datos estás trabajando. Tus 119 series ¿Son columnas de un data.frame? ¿Columnas/filas de una matriz? R tiene las funciones de la familia `*apply()` que son exactamente para lo que buscas, repetir el mismo procedimiento sobre múltiples datos. La función correcta y la forma de aplicarla depende de la estructura de datos input y de lo que esperes como salida. Si pones un ejemplo mínimo de la estructura de datos con la que estás trabajando y de como aplicas las funciones a cada serie obtendrás una respuesta.

Comment: He modificado la descripción añadiendo mis datos. Espero que esto aclare más el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Va una respuesta, deberías testearla con cuidado porque al no tener los datos crudos pruebo la solución en un data set distinto al tuyo.

Para no complicar las cosas voy a hacer de cuenta que los datos `iris` que vienen en R son una serie de tiempo. No lo son, pero tienen una estructura similar y debería ser suficiente para probar el código. Las columnas `1:4` serán los datos de interés.

La idea es usar `lapply()` para pasar una función a cada elemento de una lista. Como los data.frame son listas también funciona. No sé casi nada de series de tiempo, trabajo casi siempre con datos transversales, pero el problema de la pregunta es más de iteración que de evaluación de resultados. Aviso porque quizás esté haciendo algo no muy adecuado para el análisis de series de tiempo.

## Estabilizar la serie

`lapply()` permite funciones lambda, es decir, funciones anónimas que se definen directamente en la llamada. Sin embargo a veces el código queda más limpio si se define la función aparte y se le asigna un nombre. Para solucionar este problema se define la función `estabilizar()` que:

1. Calcula el nivel de lambda y le asigna el nombre `lambda_calculado`
2. Hace la transformación BoxCox para el nivel de lambda calculado.

Así:

```
  estabilizar <- function(x) {
  lambda_calculado <- BoxCox.lambda(x)
  BoxCox(x, lambda = lambda_calculado)
}
```

Cuando la apliquemos con `lapply()` la función a "ver" en `x` a cada una de las columnas y va a dar como output al output de la última función interna que se evaluó. En este caso es `BoxCox()`

```
# Librerías
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
library(broom)

estabilizada <- lapply(iris[, -5], estabilizar)
estabilizada <- as.data.frame(estabilizada)
```

La segunda línea es para regresarlo a data.frame, porque el `lapply()` regresa una lista.

## Hacer los test de estacionalidad

Pruebo con el `pp.test()` y el `adf.test()`, que están en la librería `tseries()`. La librería `broom()` tiene la función genérica `tidy()` con métodos para pasar a data.frame el output de prácticamente cualquier modelo. La vamos a usar para ahorrarnos hacer el subset y organizar el output de cada test. La idea es:

1. Aplicar el test a cada columna y obtener una lista con los resultados de cada test.
2. Convertir el output de cada test en un data.frame de una sola fila con `tidy()`
3. Reunir a esos data.frame de una fila en un solo data frame.

Los pasos 2 y 3 se hacen en la misma línea.

```
pruebas_adf <- lapply(falsa_serie[, -5], adf.test)
do.call(rbind, lapply(pruebas_adf, tidy))

pruebas_pp <- lapply(falsa_serie[, -5], pp.test)
do.call(rbind, lapply(pruebas_pp, tidy))
```

Si tienes dudas sobre `lapply()` la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177939/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-lapply-do-call-y-map) puede ayudarte. Si no funciona con tus datos quizás sea necesario que pongas un encale o un ejemplo **utilizable** de los mismos.

> Pegar en la pregunta el output de `dput(head(datos))` suele ser más fácil que enlazar capturas de pantalla, ocupa menos ancho de banda y almacenamiento y garantiza que la respuesta se adecúa a los datos reales. Tómalo en cuenta para próximas preguntas/respuesta.